# render error messages with js form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, error-handling

I changed my form to remote, and while the form now works, the error messages are no longer displaying if there's an error.

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
```

is there a good wear to get the messages to show again?

below is my controller...

thank you.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.js { render :js => "window.location = '#{edit_post_path @post}'" }
    format.html { redirect_to [:edit, @post] }
  else
    format.js { render :js => @post.errors }
    format.html { redirect_to '/', :error => "Could not save comment" }      
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.js { render :js => "window.location = '#{edit_post_path @post}'" }
    format.html { redirect_to [:edit, @post] }
  else
    format.js { }
    format.html { redirect_to '/', :error => "Could not save comment" }      
  end
end

# update.js.erb

$(document).find("form").prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render("shared/error_messages", :formats => [:html])) %>');
```

Comment: It does become a little sloppy when you start sticking if else conditions in something like update.js.erb trying to handle whether the model was saved or not